# How can I change color of badges in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to change color of all badges in VS Code, eg. the explorer badge (the blue circle with "1" in it) in VS Code.

[image: Explorer badge]

How can I do that? I searched and found:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "badge.background": "#A00" // Red
}
```

However, the only affected thing I can see is the badge in Source control. The badge in Explorer is still blue.

[image: Source control badge]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the color of the badges on the ActivityBar try these `colorCustomizations`:

```
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {

    "activityBarBadge.foreground": "#000",
    "activityBarBadge.background": "#FFF"
  }
```